# prove or disprove: $(null\, \phi)^0 = span(\phi)$ for a nonzero linear functional $\phi$ acting on a finite-dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

so basically I've got two "proofs"; one proving the equality in the title holds and the other disproving it but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Here is the question and my two proofs:

Q: Let $\phi \in V^{\prime}$ be a nonzero linear functional acting on the finite-dimensional vector space $V$. prove or disprove $(null\, \phi)^0 = span(\phi)$.

1. proof the equality holds:
   $$\begin{aligned} dim\,(null \,\phi)^0 &= dim\, V -dim\, (null \ \phi) \\ &=dim \, range(\phi) \\ &=1 \end{aligned}$$
   since $\phi \in (null \, \phi)^0 $ and $(null\, \phi)^0 $ is one-dimensional we conclude that $(null\, \phi)^0 = span(\phi)$.
2. proof the equality fails  to hold:

Let $u_1 \ldots u_n $ be a basis of $null \, \phi$. We can extend it to become a basis of $V$. Let $u_1 \ldots u_n v_1 \ldots v_m$ be a basis of $V$. Now we define a linear functional $\psi$ by letting $\psi(u_i)=0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and choosing $\psi(v_j)$ for $1 \leq j \leq m$ such that there is no scalar $\gamma$ such that $\psi(v_j)=\gamma \phi (v_j)$ for all $1 \leq j \leq m$. Hence we have $\psi\in (null\, \phi)^0$ but $\psi \not \in span(\phi)$ disproving $(null\, \phi)^0 = span(\phi)$.

So what am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...and choosing $\psi(v_j)$ for $1 \leq j \leq m$ such that there is no scalar $\gamma$ such that $\psi(v_j)=\gamma \phi (v_j)$ for all $1 \leq j \leq m$." There will be no such choice possible. As $\phi$ is a functional, the nullspace has codimension $1$ (i.e. $m = 1$), and every functional that shares its nullspace is a non-zero scalar multiple of $\phi$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks, I get it now. I was going insane over this.